# Heavy cost (99%) for insert in query execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, insert, query-optimization, execution-time

I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT c.irn, 
       pLog.policingname, 
       ce.* 
INTO   #caselist 
FROM   employeereminder_ilog ce 
       JOIN cases c 
         ON ce.caseid = c.caseid 
       JOIN policinglog pLog 
         ON ( ce.logdatetimestamp BETWEEN 
              pLog.startdatetime AND pLog.finishdatetime ) 
WHERE  ce.logdatetimestamp BETWEEN @start_pre AND @end_pre
```

employeereminder_iLOG is a pretty huge table, around 32M rows. 
POLICINGLOG has around 50 rows.
CASES around 0.5m rows.
@start_pre and @end_pre are predefined variabled around 30 minutes apart.

This query took around 30 minutes to run, and returns around 600 results.

I was trying to find way to speed up the query by looking at the execution plan. I couldn't work out why however the insert was taking up 99% of the query, as opposed to the select from employeereminder_iLOG .

[image]

So, my questions are:

1. Why is the cost coming from the insert, and not the select from employeereminder_iLOG.
2. Is it possible to speed up this query?

Comment: Looks like the result set it quite large and your TEMPDB located on the slow storage. Just an idea - try to replate temporary table to the table variable. Server will eat up a lot of memory, but speed should be much better.

Comment: The query only returns around 600-700 results.

Comment: How many indexes you have? Row length? I guess it's because page splitting: check your Page Splits/sec counter.

Comment: Another question - what if you will just issue a select statement without inserting anything to the temp table ? How the plan looks like in that case ?

Comment: Can you post the XML version of the execution plan? (Preferably actual execution plan rather than estimated if you have it)

Comment: Without addressing the insert operator cost -- do you have any covering indexes on the employeereminder_ilog heap table? What other indexes does Cases have (I blindly would have guessed that Cases would have been clustered on caseid)? Have you checked for blocking on reads? Have you checked wait stats while the query is running?